# a manifold on which every smooth function has at least two local minima

Tags: smooth-manifolds, morse-theory

I am wondering whether there exists such a compact and connected manifold such that **every** smooth function on it has at least two local minima.

Because it is compact, so there is at least one local minimum. But is it possible that there are always more than one?

This is of course related to the Morse theory.

Comment: Take a small open patch on your manifold and construct a function on it that has a single minimum and which vanishes at the boundary.  Extend by $0$.

Comment: If the question is about _connected_ manifolds (or conversely, if disconnected manifolds are of interest), please edit to add this condition explicitly.

Comment: You can certainly have functions with two local minima, however this is not a necessary condition for every Morse function in this case. Being connected your manifold you can  start from any Morse function and use handle body cancelling technique to get rid of "redundant" local minima and only one will remain. The same thing for local maxima. If you allow for more than one connected component then you must necessarily have more than one local minima